# How to get text onClick from Listview that is using SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get key+value (All text of row) item text when user is clicking a row, but i cant figure out how to do it, heres the code:

```
   lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

   simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            scriptList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            new String[] {"value","key"},
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2 });

   lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

     //######
     // HOW DO I GET THE ITEM TEXT (BOTH PARAMS, KEY + VALUE)?

    });
```

Comment: have you tried assigning a name to the string so you can call it in the method onItemClick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parent.getItemAtPostion` returns the item at position. In your case `scriptList` should be an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`. The item at position is therefore an `HashMap<String, String>`.

```
HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPostion(position);
String value = item.get("value");
String key = item.get("key");
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position` argument in `onItemClick` method to get the data from your dataset.

```
HashMap<String, String> clickedItem = (HashMap<String, String>) scriptList.get(position);
String value = clickedItem.get("value");
String key = clickedItem.get("key");
```